# add the option "show password " to asp.net login control

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, authentication, login-control

I used asp.net login control in ored to log my site the issue is that I want to add an opption to show the password (instead of asterisk) but I have no access to the password textbox so I can't change its textmode.

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to change the default behaviour ?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar: Probably because the asterisks are a minor PITA for long passwords, generally completely unnecessary for web apps and a royal PITA when typing them in using a phone device which often doesn't pick the same letter you think you are typing.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Show password option by using Checkbox]

```
onchange="document.getElementById('password').type = this.checked ? 'text' : 'password'"
```

Even we can use the onclick event of the checkbox. [Refference code](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2016/01/show-password-option-in-aspnet-using-checkbox.html)

Answer (score 4):

`LayoutTemplate` is available in the login control, you can completely change the layout and whatever else you want. Here is a completeled layout designed for a login page that I have used in one project.

```
 <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                        ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                        ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" CssClass="hint hide" Text="Remember me next time." />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color: Red;">
                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="Login1" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I made my show/hide password control incorporated both Muhammad Akhtar's and Kesavarapu Venkatesh's answers. I used the ASP.NET Login control like Muhammad, but also used a checkbox with very similar code like Kesavarapu. The difference between my checkbox and his was the ID the JavaScript is getting, which is "<%=((TextBox)logUsers.FindControl("Password")).ClientID %>" instead of "password", since we are accessing the ASP.NET login control instead of a regular textbox.

```
<asp:Login ID="logUsers" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" FailureText="" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" OnAuthenticate="logUsers_Authenticate" UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="Username is required.">
    <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:Login>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('<%=((TextBox)logUsers.FindControl("Password")).ClientID %>').type = this.checked ? 'text' : 'password'" /> Show password
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this using a toggle button instead of a checkbox and used bootstrap's "eye" icon.
It behaves like the checkbox, but just a different look

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>').type = document.getElementById('<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>').type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye mb-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8M1.173 8a13 13 0 0 1 1.66-2.043C4.12 4.668 5.88 3.5 8 3.5s3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13 13 0 0 1 14.828 8q-.086.13-.195.288c-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755C11.879 11.332 10.119 12.5 8 12.5s-3.879-1.168-5.168-2.457A13 13 0 0 1 1.172 8z"></path>
        <path d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5M4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0"></path>
    </svg>
</button>
```

you could also pull this out into a function so you can call it for a confirm password field

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function toggleShowPassword(clientId) {  
        let x = document.getElementById(clientId);  
        if (x.type === "password") {  
            x.type = "text";  
        } else {  
            x.type = "password";  
        }   
     }
</script>
```

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" onclick="toggleShowPassword('<%= txtPassword.ClientID %>')">  
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye mb-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">  
        <path d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8M1.173 8a13 13 0 0 1 1.66-2.043C4.12 4.668 5.88 3.5 8 3.5s3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13 13 0 0 1 14.828 8q-.086.13-.195.288c-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755C11.879 11.332 10.119 12.5 8 12.5s-3.879-1.168-5.168-2.457A13 13 0 0 1 1.172 8z"></path>  
        <path d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5M4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0"></path>  
    </svg>
</button>
```